# What Raspberry Pi should I buy?

Tags: pi-models

I want to buy a Raspberry Pi, but I don't know which one. I want to start with machine learning and artificial intelligence. I thought the Raspberry Pi 2 b+ was enough, but with the 3 and the Zero now I'm so confused.

Comment: The features are very obvious.  If you have a *more specific* question about them, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Get the RPi3, considering it to be the same price it's the better deal. There is also a port of Google's TensorFlow which allows it to run on the 3's new A53 based core. Good Luck!

(https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Why is it a better deal?

Comment: If they're the same price, and one offers more performance and features. I'd say its a better deal unless the increased power consumption is that much more of a worry to you

Comment: Right, but you don't specify that in your answer. It sounds like the OP doesn't understand what the difference between the three mentioned models is. Why get a 3 over a 2, or even a zero?